# Excel Formula to Match Items Within a Date Range

Tags: excel

I'm trying to match a product sale date with the range date of sales. I have the following so far:

```
=INDEX(A3,MATCH(1,((H:H=A3)*(B:B>=I3)*(B:B<=J3)),0))
```

I'm trying to have the formula produce a result if column A matches column H 
and if column B is between column I & J, where J may not have occurred yet.

[image: I have added a photo of my sample spreadsheet here]

EDIT: column E15 isn't returning any results
[See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKbtU.png)

Comment: and return what?  You are returning the actual product name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=IF(SUM(($H$3:$H$12=$A3)*($I$3:$I$12<=B3)*(IF($J$3:$J$12<>"",$J$3:$J$12,TODAY()+1)>$B3)),$A$3,"")
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Thank you! this is what i'm looking for for the most part, but this isn't working on all the rows for some reason. I've tried using ctrl+shift+enter, but it still is not working during my test for a couple products. any idea why?

Comment: did you fix the references to your actual data?  Are your dates all true dates and not text that looks like dates?  If it works on some but not others, look to the data first.

Comment: I have checked the data, and it seems to be checking out. I have edited my post to add a photo of the cell that is not populating a result. thanks

Comment: found the issue: you were correct - extra spaces in column A. One last question: if I wanted to use the same formula to test if column B occurred 24 hours before column I, how would I do that?

Comment: @rauf741 new Questions get new posts.  This question has been answered and I would appreciate you marking it as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer. But days in Excel = `1` so just add `-1` from column I in the test.  If you cannot get it to work from that ask a new question with data and expected ouput.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use something like this in the cell where you want the value to occur?

```
=IF(A1=H1,IF(AND(I2<B2,B2<J2),TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

You can then replace "True" and "False" with other statements to produce different outcomes.

Comment: This would not work, as some rows may not be lined up